# Makefile generating multiple instances of a library

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

What is the best way to generate multiple instances of library files.
For instance, considering the following example:

```
Lib.h (Inst1)        Lib.h (Inst2)
    ¦                     ¦
    ----------------------
              ¦
            Lib.c
              ¦
      ----------------
      ¦              ¦
   FolderA       FolderB
   (Lib.a)       (Lib.a)     -> Here are 2 different instances of the library
```

NB: Both versions of Lib.a will have the same name but different contents.
This could happen for instance when includes contain different #define values:

```c
#define VAR1 0 -> Defined in Lib.h (Inst1)
#define VAR1 5 -> Defined in Lib.h (Inst2)
```

=> several versions of Lib.a

I thought about having a main makefile containing all the possible combination needed, but that will quickly become unmanageable.

Can this be done in a structured way? What is the typical approach to do something like that?

Comment: Why do you want to have multiple instances of the same lib? You can just add another target in your Makefile and do the simple `cp src dst`, but what is the purpose?

Comment: Well, these libs have same names but different contents. That is what I meant by multiple instances.
eg. 
    #define VAR1 0   -> Defined in Lib.h (Inst1).......
    #define VAR1 5   -> Defined in Lib.h (Inst2).......
=> several versions of Lib.a

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/fortran-and-gnu-make/ I know it uses fortran source codes, but it's just a matter of replacing Fortran code with C code. It's very similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @mko, but that is not quite it unfortunately. Your example compiles 2 different outputs out of 2 different inputs, using different names.

Comment: @progLearner no problem.

Comment: It's not overly clear what you're trying to accomplish -- Are `Lib.h (inst1)` and `Lib.a (inst2)` the same file, and you want to output based on their contents, or are these different files in different directories?   How do you intend to map the target directory from the particular instance of `Lib.h`.   There's a bunch of ways to do what you're describing depending on your intentions...

Comment: The structured way must come either from a big manual list (which you want to avoid) or from a naming scheme which plays with prefixes for the different names and postfixes for the different versions. Is there some organization which you deem viable? Could you sketch it in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to generate `lib.a` based on the contents of an existing `lib.h` (there's one copy of the file, but it can have different contents...), you could do something like:

```
target_dir = $(shell some commands to figure out desired target dir from lib.h)

all: ${target_dir}/lib.a

%/lib.a: common/lib.h
     @echo doing some commands to build lib.a
```

Which would build lib.a in the correct directory based on the contents of the lib.h.

If, on the other hand, you have multiple copies of lib.h, then you want something to the effect of:

```
%/lib.a: %/lib.h
     @echo doing some commands to build lib.a from $^
```

Finally, if the directory names don't line up, you could map it using a bunch of rules:

```
FolderA/lib.a: Inst1/lib.h
FolderB/lib.a: Inst2/lib.h

%/lib.a:
    @echo doing some commands to build lib.a from $^
```

If you want to generate multiple versions of lib.h based on some array or something like that, then that's another story...

Comment: Thanks @HardcoreHenry for all these options. I should probably also add Lib.c as input.

Comment: There's another thing. What if we have 100's of c file and each of these files #include a sets of include files. Do we need to define dependencies for each individual file manually? That could become really tedious.

Comment: You really need a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.  It's not hard to generate the dependencies automatically, but again, there's multiple ways of doing it depending on what are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comment, maybe you can do like this:

1. Define the rules for compiling libVar1Eq0.a with VAR1 == 0
2. Define the rules for compiling libVar1Eq5.a with VAR1 == 5
3. Define the rule for target `FolderA/lib.a` as `ln -s libVar1Eq0.a FolderA/lib.a`
4. Define the rule for target `FolderB/lib.a` as `ln -s libVar1Eq5.a FolderB/lib.a`

If you have a lot of different lib.h, it can easily be automated.

Comment: Thanks @Ptaq666. That's an interesting one. Is that a conventional approach or rather hacky?

Comment: Hard to tell. Maybe a little bit hacky. But linux shared libs are actually organized this way. E.g.: `libc.so.6 -> libc-2.24.so` linker links against `libc.so.6`, which is the symlink to the appropriate lib version, `libc-2.24.so` in this case.

Comment: Alright then, Linux cannot be a bad reference. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variable at `make` invocation.

Imagine your makefile is:

```
all: $(DIR)/lib.so

$(DIR)/lib.so: lib.c
    $(CC) -shared -I$(DIR) -o $@ $<
```

You can call it with: `make DIR=Inst1`

So you can generate all your library in one call:

```
#! /bin/sh
for I in Inst*; do
    make DIR=$I
done
```

Comment: Thanks for that @purplepsycho. This looks like a good first step. Now, how would you handle the case where instead of Lib.c, you have 100's of .c files (each of which possibly compiling using multiple instances of .h files). 
If -I$(DIR) points to the first sets of include instances and -I$(DIR2) to the second sets, how would I handle the case where a File1.c needs Lib.h (var1), but File2.c needs Lib.h (var2). It would become really messy to define individual dependencies. Is there a typical approach to solve this?
This would cause a conflict:
    $(CC) -shared -I$(DIR) -I$(DIR2) -o $@ $<